# Migrating Java portlet to run on Wildfly

Tags: java, wildfly, portlet

I have been assigned to restructure an existing java portlet application to run it on Wildfly. Has anyone faced with this situation before? I would appreciate any directions or pointers on this.

Thanks

Comment: A JSR 286 portlet environment?  This will not be trivial but you may want to look at something like [Liferay](https://www.liferay.com/) as they have historically been a portal type environment.  They can run on Wildfly.